# Trying to insert multiple rows via a trigger (on insert) is causing errors

Tags: mysql, triggers

Trying to use a trigger to insert multiple rows in a table (on insert) but it's only working with one row. I get an error return from the form (nothing specific, just that there was an error with the original insert)

Works fine with 1 row, but multiple crashes. What's wrong with this syntax?

```
BEGIN
set @moonid = 1;
insert into quicknotedesc (custid,moonid) VALUES (New.id,(@moonid)),(New.id,(@moonid+1));
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the trigger body appears to be valid.

With almost every SQL client, there is a mechanism to detect an error condition and to retrieve the error message.  Maybe the error is because of an attempt to violate a unique constraint on the `custid` column of `quicknotedesc`, or some other constraint violation. We're just guessing.

Consider enabling the client to retrieve the actual error message. And consider  testing the behavior of the trigger from another client, like the MySQL command line client.

---

Again, to answer the question that was asked:

The syntax of the trigger body appears to be valid.

Demonstration:

```
CREATE TABLE quicknotedesc 
( custid  BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
, moonid  BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (custid, moonid)
);

CREATE TABLE foo
( id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT 
);
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER foo_ai
AFTER INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @moonid = 1;
  INSERT INTO quicknotedesc (custid,moonid) VALUES (New.id,(@moonid)),(New.id,(@moonid+1));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (NULL) ;

1 row(s) affected

SELECT * FROM quicknotedesc ;

custid  moonid  
------  ------
     1       1
     1       2
```

Comment: I can't test the logging process right now but neither of the inserts are primary keys. There is a primary key that i'm not inserting that auto increments. Is it possible that via the process of a trigger it's not doing the auto increment as it would from otherwise using the SQL console? I definitely want all rows to have the same custid and there's without a doubt no foreign/primary key tied to it

Comment: A little bit more about the code you wrote. You set it as for each row, but the insert that activates this trigger is a single row. It's entering a new customer in the customer table. I'm using a trigger to generate 11 inserts in a different table with predetermined moonid, with that same custid. Is this something that could explain my issue?

Comment: Ok i found the issue. The primary key (which i'm not manually inserting) seems to not know to auto increment automatically when inserting multiple rows at the same time. How could I circumvent that? I was thinking getting a select for the counter and manually increment it myself but maybe there's a cleaner way?

Comment: @Sigma:  to have a value automatically assigned to an AUTO_INCREMENT column on an INSERT, we can supply a NULL value for that column. We can do that with a `INSERT ...VALUES` statement (as demonstrated on the foo table in this answer). We can also have a SELECT statement return a NULL value for a column in an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement. e.g. `INSERT INTO foobar (autoinccol, someothercol) SELECT NULL AS autoinccol, some_expression AS someothercol FROM ...`.

Comment: @Sigma:  a value assigned to the AUTO_INCREMENT column is *not* available in `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, but it will be available in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. All triggers in MySQL are "for each row".

Comment: Thanks a ton, with this I was able to sort it out and get it to work. Cheers!